# How to delete "\" characters in R string?

Tags: r

I have the following string and I need to have this characters without `"\"` and an extra pair of `""`.
So every element of this string looks like  `"\"USD:US dollar\""`, while I should have `"USD:US dollar"`.

This below is the string.

```
string = c("\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", "\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", "\"USD:US dollar\"", 
"\"USD:US dollar\"")
```

How can I have clean character elements?

Comment: There is not a single `\ ` character in the strings, as far as I can see. Instead you’re seeing `"` characters, which are shown as escaped, i.e. as `\"`. This doesn’t cause problems when actually handling or displaying the strings, it’s merely shown when the strings are displayed via (implicit) `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the double quote that is creating the issue.  We can use `gsub`

```
gsub('"', '', string)
```